# Cannot open include file

Tags: qt, vulkan

I have installed Qt 5.12.3 and  Vulkan SDK  and VULKAN_SDK environment variable set.Then I tried to build the vulkan examples in Qt\Examples\Qt-5.12.3\vulkan\hellovulkancubes, and the Qt compiler  gave me the following information:

"D:\Qt 5.12.3\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui/qvulkaninstance.h(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: “vulkan/vulkan.h”: No such file or directory."

Could somebody give me  some guidance on this problem? By the way, I am using Win10 pro x64.

I tried to check the environment variables and check if something wrong with my OS.

Comment: On linux thre are packages, installing stuff is much easier than windows. You can just search for the .h file missing and install the package that has it. So I think that developing on linux is easier.

Comment: Basically on windows the only reason this would happen is if you didn't have vulkan/vulkan.h in your path.  Does your path point to the directory where vulkan/vulkan.h exists?  If not, there you go, if it does, show us the value of this path variable.

Comment: That you have `VULKAN_SDK` set does not mean the compiler knows about it. Add it to include paths.